# Multiple files download in Chrome using HTML5 Drag & Drop

Tags: html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, download

I know that it is possible to download a file in Chrome using HTML5 Drag & Drop. It is implemented in Gmail.

Is it possible to download more than one file in one step using Drag & Drop and HTML/JavaScript only?

Comment: Please have a look at this one also [HTML5 File Sync framework](https://github.com/speedyankur/FileSyncFramework)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Here's a link. http://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-drag-and-drop-multiple-file-uploader/

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Chrome has implemented a special protocol for drag and drop out of the browser.

See http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/dnd/basics/#toc-desktop-dnd-out

(No other browsers support this that I know of)

Comment: So... How to download more than a single file in Chrome using D&D? Any code example?

Comment: The question is if it's possible for multiple files, the link you posted doesn't answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
ev.dataTransfer.items.add(file1);
ev.dataTransfer.items.add(file2);
```

link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItemList/add